# Error: could not find function "readDICOM"

Tags: r, function, find

I have installed the requested package

```
install.packages('devtools')
library(devtools)
```

The working directory was set correctly, but when I was trying to open the data, R failed to read it. And this is what I got as a feedback.

```
slice = readDICOM ("IM-0001-0011.dcm")
```

> Error: could not find function "readDICOM"

And I can't get why `readDICOM` is not there and what should I do to change it.

Comment: Have you even tried googling this error message before posting a question? This [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35697799/error-in-reading-a-dicom-file-using-readdicom-in-r) claims to have the solution and was second link in Google after searching for your error message (first link was your question).

Comment: Yes, I tried, and I saw it, but the error is different in that one

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install and load the `oro.dicom` package.

Comment: Hi, thank you.  I have installed oro.dicom, but the error (Error: could not find function "readDCOM") is still there. Is there in your opinion, anything else, I can try to do to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You likely installed the package but didn't load it.  use `library('oro.dicom')` and it should work